# How can i show this data in my html with ionic 2 from a json?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is simply to explain, I have a side menu in my app and when I click on the first option ("Carne") it opens another page which should show all recipes of the `type: "Carne"`.

My problem is that I can't show the recipes, the page is still empty when I use a `ngFor` for showing the details of a recipe.

[Page of "Carne"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbtYE.png)

html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar >
    <ion-title >{{tipo.tipo}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

<ion-card >
  <ion-card-content *ngFor="let receta of recetas">
    <p>{{receta.Nombre}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>


</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

json:

```
"data": [
        {
            "tipo":"Carne",
            "recetas":[
                {
                    "Nombre":"Big Mac.",
                    "Complejidad": "1",
                 ...
                }
            ]
        }
```

.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/ionic-page';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-lista',
  templateUrl: 'lista.html',
})
@IonicPage({
  name:'lista-page'
})
export class ListaPage {


  private tipo: string="";
  private recetas: any="";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http) {
    this.tipo = this.navParams["data"];
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    this.http.get('/assets/data/datosReceta.json')
      .map((res)=>res.json())
      .subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(this.tipo);
        for(let tipo of data["data"]){
          if(tipo["tipo"]==this.tipo){
            this.recetas=tipo["recetas"];
            console.log(this.tipo);
          }
        }
    },(rej)=>{console.error("Error",rej)})  
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you create a plunkr page with the same issue?

Comment: I can create a plunkr but i have to create all myApp folder... I mean all the ionic folder

Comment: If you log this.recetas instead of this.tipo do you get the expected result?

Comment: No, I have nothing in the console. Sounds weird

Comment: what is the actual result of data and tipo in the get result

Comment: data is the json file and tipo is the type of recipe in the json.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had got the solution. Just I didn't declarate the push in app.component.ts

I had got this:

```
openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.push(ListaPage, page);
  }
```

And I had to do this:

```
 openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.push(ListaPage, page.tipo);
  }
```